# How to create very thin, very tall whitespace?

Tags: typography

I have several macros which produce bracketed expressions, with bracket size automatically adjusted using `\right(` and `\left)`. This *almost* always works well. However, there are times when I feel that slightly larger brackets would be preferable - because the bracketed expression is so long, contains multiple brackets, etc.

Since I don't want to rewrite these macros, I figured out a work-around solution. I would just insert manually something tall (maybe `\sum^x`), use `\phantom` so that it does not display, and then try roll back by inserting a number of `\!`'s. It works, but it's dirty.

How can I (nicely) create a whitespace which is tall (so that automatically sized delimiters become tall as well) but which only takes up a negligible amount of horizontal space?

Comment: `\vphantom` perhaps????

Comment: `\vphantom{foo}` is the height of foo and zero width

Comment: This works! Thank you. I had no idea this command exists.

Comment: Also possible is `\rule{0pt}{1cm}` etc. to create a rule with zero width.

Comment: @IanThompson: True, but this requires explicit setting of the height. (But a nice idea)